# Add a Wordpress post grid (latest posts) by author to a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, module, blogs, author, divi

I have created a custom post type called Professionals.  I am using the Divi Theme Builder to display each professional with their own dynamic content (using advanced custom fields).  At the bottom of each professional's page, I would like to add a divi blog module showing 3 of their most recent blog posts. Here's what I have so far - but nothing is showing on the page.

```php
function add_author_recent_posts() {
    $author = get_the_author(); // defines your author ID if it is on the post in question
    $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'professionals',
                 'post_status' => 'publish',
                 'author'=>$author,
                 'posts_per_page' => 3, // the number of posts you'd like to show
                 'orderby' => 'date',
                 'order' => 'DESC'
                 );
     $results = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($results->have_posts()) {
      $results->the_post();
      the_title();
      echo '</hr>'; // puts a horizontal line between results if necessary 
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_recent_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you're calling the [get_the_author](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/) function. You've added it on `init` hook, and at this point, the Author returned will be none:

```php
function add_author_recent_posts() {
    $author = get_the_author();
    echo $author; die;
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_recent_posts' );
```

So, I'll suggest you to place it on `the_content` filter, appending yours posts to the original content:

```php
function add_author_recent_posts($content) {
  $author = get_the_author();
  $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'post',
               'post_status' => 'publish',
               'author'=>$author,
               'posts_per_page' => 3, 
               'orderby' => 'date',
               'order' => 'DESC'
               );
   $results = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($results->have_posts()) {
    $results->the_post();
    $content .= get_the_title();
    $content .= '</hr>'; 
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_author_recent_posts' );
```